Firebase Messaging. Web SDK. Setup Delivery report to BigQuery
I have a Web application with Push Notifications sent to this app. Push Notifications itself works fine.
I need to set up Delivery report for Push Notifications on a Web Application.
I've read documentation
But, I do not really understand what exactly I have to do in the source code on client side.
What I did:
file: firebase-messaging-sw.js
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
 // Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here. Other Firebase libraries
 // are not available in the service worker.
 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
 importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

 // Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
 // your app's Firebase config object.
 // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "XXX",
    authDomain: "XXX.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "XXX",
    storageBucket: "XXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXX",
    appId: "XXX"
});

 console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Firebase App is initialized');

 // Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
 // messages.
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();

 console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Firebase messaging', messaging);

 console.log('Call experimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled')
 try {
     experimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled(messaging, true)
 }
 catch (e) {
     console.log('error', e)
 }
 console.log('Set deliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled')
 messaging.deliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled = true

 console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] DeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled was set to true', messaging);
 
// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// Keep in mind that FCM will still show notification messages automatically 
// and you should use data messages for custom notifications.
// For more info see: 
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});


in my web application:
    <script src="~/js/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "XXX",
      authDomain: "XXX.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "XXX",
      storageBucket: "XXX.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "XXX",
      appId: "XXX"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    
    console.log('App: firebase messaging is initialized', messaging)
    
     console.log('Call experimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled')
     
     try {
         experimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled(messaging, true)
     }
     catch (e) {
         console.log('error', e)
     }
    
     console.log('Set deliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled')
     messaging.deliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled = true
    
    console.log('firebase messaging after setting up deliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled', messaging)

    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
        console.log('Message received. ', payload);
        // Update the UI to include the received message.
        appendMessage(JSON.stringify(payload), 'Push notification');
    });

    getStartToken();
 
    function appendMessage(msgText, msgHeader){
        let msgElem = document.getElementById("msg");
        let header = '[' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + '] ' + msgHeader;
        msgElem.innerHTML = '<b>' + header + ':</b> ' + msgText 
            + '<br/>' + msgElem.innerHTML; 
    }
    
    var currentFcmToken;
    function getStartToken() {
        messaging.getToken({vapidKey: 'XXX'})
        .then((currentToken) => {
            console.log("Messaging token received from the FCM server");
            currentFcmToken = currentToken;
            if (currentToken) {
                appendMessage(currentToken, "Web device token from FCM");
            } else {
                // Show permission request.
                RequestPermission();
                setTokenSentToServer(false);
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            setTokenSentToServer(false);
        });
    }

    function RequestPermission() {
        messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function (permission) {
                appendMessage(permission, 'Permission')
                if (permission === 'granted') {
                    console.log("Permission granted");                    
                    getStartToken();    //calls method again to send token to server
                } else {
                    console.log("Permission denied");
                }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }


After that I expect to see "Received" messages on FCM report.
But, I see the only "Sends"
enter image description here
Also, I've set up link FCM to BigQuery. I expect some records in the created dataset. But, dataset is empty.
